# Load in browser function will not load resources

Tags: html, css, atom-editor, adobe-brackets

When I click the `index.html` - the page will load **right** with all its `css/bootstrap` resources.

When I load the page via `Atom/Brackets`/ other editors by "open in Chrome", then I get errors and the page will not find the bootstrap files:

```
bootstrap.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I load them with :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>


          <script type="text/javascript" src="../Bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

         <script src="../Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My folder structure is (loaded from start folder/index):
[image]

Where inside bootstrap all files exist.

Comment: what is the "url" for the index.html file if you open it from the editor?

Comment: I am not sure , I just click open on web, why? What could go wrong there? Thank you .

Comment: This problem is related to Absolute/Relative addressing. So first thing look at the url in the browser and find the differences (when you access the file directly and when using brackets to open it)

Comment: So the path is ok, just the right path to the file - public->start->index.html. Not sure what to do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you tried moving the index.html to the public (root) folder and changed your hrefs to href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" that it would work from the editor too